# genetic algorithm for substitution cipher cracking doesnt approach high fitness values

Tags: python, algorithm, cryptography, genetic-algorithm, substitution

i have been trying to solve simple substitution ciphers with the use of a genetic algorithm, but have a problem where i dont get even close to the expected solution with 10000+ generations with a population of about 200 while haveing plateaued for about the last 8000 generations and im not quite sure if the problem lies within my fitness function, in the way i breed the population, or, most likely, both.

I then realised, that if i not only take the first child of each set of parents(more on that later when i explain my crossover) but both resulting children, the fitness value just jumps around rather randomly with me getting very low "highest fitness in generation" values even after a lot of generations, which make me think the problem is most likely the crossover itself.

The whole program can be found here:
http://pythonfiddle.com/genetic-algorithm/

im testing with following string as first argument:
"iq ifcc vqqr fb rdq vfllcq na rdq cfjwhwz hr bnnb hcc hwwhbsqvqbre hwq vhlq"

its supposed to become: "we will meet in the middle of the library at noon all arrangements are made"

The gene material in this algorithm consists of a string containing each letter of the alphabet exactly once while the order of the letters corresponds to the substituted letter in the encrypted string. So in:
"etaoinshrdlcumwfgypbvkjxqz"
e would substitute a, t would substitute b etc.

The fitness function combines a score of letter frequency, bigram frequency and match with most common words.

For breeding i choose the top 20%, 5% of less healthy individuals and then mutate 2% of them

The crossover works like this:

```
# splice genes of parents together at random point in gene material
def crossover(male, female):
    rand = random.randint(2,24)
    child = male[:rand] + female[rand:]
    child_two = male[rand:] + female[:rand]
    repair_one = repair(child)
    repair_two = repair(child_two)
    return [repair_one, repair_two];

#repairs the child string to conform to gene standards(every gene is unique)
# cretain as much of the parent strings as possible
def repair(child):
    repaired_child = child
    temp = []

    rand = random.randint(1,2)
    omitted = []
    double = []
    for value in GENES:
        count = child.count(value)
        if count == 0:
            omitted.append(value)
        elif count == 2:
            double.append(value)

    for value in double:
        if value > 1:
            repaired_child = replacenth(repaired_child, value, omitted.pop(), rand)
    return repaired_child;
```

i choose a random point in the 26 letter long strings of the 2 parents,
cut them both there, join the halves of the parentstring.

mother + father is the first child father + mother is the second. Of course as every letter in the genestring has to be unique(otherwise the cipher is unusable) i have to repair the genes afterwards. I do that by first counting how often every letter occurs, and then replacing doubled letters with letters that havent been used yet until the string only has unique letters.

I know genetic algorithms arent the best way to solve substitution ciphers, but i thought it would be an interesting thing to try and test and should be doable in a decent amount of time shouldnt it?

Any help and pointing out of errors is dearly appreciated

Comment: I ran your code and it was able to reach a fitness score of 28, which is equal to the fitness of the correct answer. So I think the main issue is that the fitness function is not able to tell the difference between English and "un udtt annm do min adsstn ly min tdhereb rm ollo rtt reerognanomw ren arsn".